# mysql null value throwing xcode error

Tags: mysql, ios, json

I have set up MySQL database and have parsed the JSON to my XCode project. However, I am getting a `THREAD 1: signal SIGABRT` error for the fourth line below. I think this is due to a null value for one of the 'location' variables in the database. Is this the reason?  And if so, how can I get it to ignore the `null` value and just leave the label blank? Thanks in advance for your time.

```
UILabel *event = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
event.text = [dict objectForKey:@"event"];

UILabel *location = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
location.text = [dict objectForKey:@"location"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It strikes me that null value is unlikely to be the problem (because you can `nil` the `text` property of a `UILabel` to remove the text). I would suspect that the problem is either:

1. I wonder if `[dict objectForKey:@"location"]` could return something other than a string, such as a `NSDictionary`? I would either `NSLog` this value (or put in a breakpoint and examine this value there) and confirm. Or put in an `NSAssert` like I have below.
2. Less likely, but I wonder if the subview with a tag of `103` is really a `UILabel`? I might examine the `location` object in the debugger to make sure. But if the view with tag of `103` is not a `UILabel`, then you might get an error.

Thus, maybe something like:

```
UILabel *location = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
NSAssert([location isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]], @"%s: view with tag 103 is not UILabel: %@", __FUNCTION__, location);
NSString *locationString = [dict objectForKey:@"location"];
NSAssert(locationString == nil || [locationString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]], @"locationString is not nil but not string either: locationString = %@", locationString);
location.text = locationString;
```

Comment: Hi Rob. I tried the code above. I kept getting the same error. However, I have now confirmed that it is the null value causing the error. I entered a value in the location variable and the code ran smoothly. Any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: @newman is `locationString` coming back as a `nil` value or a `[NSNull null]` value? When you added the above NSAssert values, did it log anything interesting?